# Swift generic object factory won't use child class initializer

Tags: ios, swift, generics, factory

I'm trying to make a factory that will take a generic type and return array of the given type. However, when I try using `T.self()` it just initializes with the superclass initializer (`Initializable` in this case). But, I have a subclass that I want initialized.

```
class Initializable {
    let object: PFObject
    init(_ object: PFObject) {
        self.object = object
    }
}

class ObjectFactory {
    class func create<T: Initializable>(objects: [AnyObject]?) -> [T] {
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            return objects.map {object in
                T.self(object)
            }
        }
        println("unable to create objects")
        return []
    }
}
```

Then when I try

`let subclasses: [Subclass] = ObjectFactory.create([subclass])`

then `subclasses` ends up being an array of `Initializable` as opposed to `Subclass`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Im confused, your factory will create a list Initializable object out of a list of some objects if they can be cast to PFObject. are you sub classing PFObject? if so it will still only create an array of your Initializable object

Comment: @NeilHorton I'm subclassing Initializable, not PFObject. So I want to have the T.self(object) be equivalent to Subclass(object), which would make an instance of Subclass with the "object" property equal to the instance of the PFObject.

Comment: How are you letting your factory know this, you cast your input to PFObject which as far as i can see Initializable and Subclass don't inherit from, so it will perform the if let, be unable to cast it and return an empty array of whatever you pass in?

Comment: @NeilHorton That's the part I'm not sure of, how to let the factory know what type to return. I was hoping that the let subclasses: [Subclass] part would do it, but it doesn't work. Are there any fixes you can think of?

Comment: No it wont be of use because you are using a returning type T which the function can only ever determine at best to be of type initializable, you need to pass the type you want to return to the function